# Code that indicates a request to the given url has succeeded

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to code a simple program that indicates the request to the given url has succeeded.

When I do this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://google.com')
print(response)
```

I get this output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

But when i change my code to this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://google.com')
if response == '<Response [200]>':
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

It prints `False`, but it should have printed `True`.

How can I fix this??

Comment: That's because the returned response is not a string as you have it ```'<Response [200]>'``` The response is a whole class object ```<class 'requests.models.Response'>```

Comment: A common [idiom](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) is to do the .get() and then: `response.raise_for_error()`. That way, if subsequent statements execute, they can confidently assume we received a good response document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the status code rather than the Response object string representation

```
print(response.status_code == 200)
```

If you wanted to compare strings, that would be

```
str(response) == '<Response [200]>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you get is not a string. It is the string representation of the response object you get.
To verify the success of your request you could use the `response.ok` function.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://google.com')
if response.ok:  # response.status_code < 400
    print("request ok")
else:
    print("request not ok")
```

If you just want a bool print, you can directly print response.ok:

```
import requests
    
response = requests.get('https://google.com')
print(response.ok)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.status_code` to get the right response code from `requests`.

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://google.com').status_code
if response == 200:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` can be `True` or `not`, so a simple `if` statement works:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
if response: # '<Response [200]>'
    print(f'True, Response: {str(response)}')
else:
    print(f'False, Response: {str(response)}')
```

Outputs:

```
True, Response: <Response [200]>
```

and all other `response`s are `False`, for example:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/__')
if response: # '<Response [200]>'
    print(f'True, Response: {str(response)}')
else:
    print(f'False, Response: {str(response)}')
```

Outputs:

```
False, Response: <Response [404]>
```